# Dynamically append OWIN JWT resource server Application clients (audiences)

Tags: c#, oauth, owin, jwt

I have a `C#` API that uses **OWIN** **JWT** for authentication.

My `startup.cs` (of my resource server) configures OAuth vis the code:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = "<the_same_issuer_as_AuthenticationServer.Api>";

    // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
    var audiences = DatabaseAccessLayer.GetAllowedAudiences(); // Gets a list of audience Ids, secrets, and names (although names are unused)

    // List the 
    List<string> audienceId = new List<string>();
    List<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider> providers = new List<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider>();
    foreach (var aud in audiences) {
        audienceId.Add(aud.ClientId);
        providers.Add(new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(aud.ClientSecret)));
    }

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = audienceId.ToArray(),
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = providers.ToArray(),
            Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = context =>
                {
                    context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("newCustomClaim", "newValue"));
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

which allows authenticated bearer tokens to be checked agains multiple ClientIDs. *This works well.*
However, my web application allows for a user to create a new Application audience (*i.e.*, a new **ClientID**, **ClientSecret**, and **ClientName** combination), but after this happens, I don't know how to get the resource server's `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` to recognize the newly created audience.

I can restart the server after a new audience so that `ConfigureOAuth()` reruns after, but this is not a good approach in the long run.

**Does anyone have any idea how to add audiences (*i.e.*, a new **ClientID**, **ClientSecret**, and **ClientName** combination) to the OWIN application `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` outside of startup.cs and `ConfigureOAuth()`?**

I have been looking to: https://docs.auth0.com/aspnetwebapi-owin-tutorial and http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/ for help, but both code examples display the same issue described above.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: yes, i also need the same thing, any news?

Answer (score 2):

The following works when using the X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider. It has been modified to use the SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider but has not been yet been tested.

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = "<the_same_issuer_as_AuthenticationServer.Api>";

    // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
    Func<IEnumerable<Audience>> allowedAudiences = () => DatabaseAccessLayer.GetAllowedAudiences();

    var bearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            AudienceValidator = (audiences, securityToken, validationParameters) =>
            {
                return allowedAudiences().Select(x => x.ClientId).Intersect(audiences).Count() > 0;
            },
            ValidIssuers = new ValidIssuers { Audiences = allowedAudiences },
            IssuerSigningTokens = new SecurityTokensTokens(issuer) { Audiences = allowedAudiences }
        })
    };
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(bearerOptions);
}

public abstract class AbstractAudiences<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public Func<IEnumerable<Audience>> Audiences { get; set; }

    public abstract IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SecurityTokensTokens : AbstractAudiences<SecurityToken>
{
    private string issuer;

    public SecurityTokensTokens(string issuer)
    {
        this.issuer = issuer;
    }

    public override IEnumerator<SecurityToken> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var aud in Audiences())
        {
            foreach (var securityToken in new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(aud.ClientSecret)).SecurityTokens)
            {
                yield return securityToken;
            };
        }
    }
}

public class ValidIssuers : AbstractAudiences<string>
{
    public override IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var aud in Audiences())
        {
            yield return aud.ClientSecret;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Danny. Total noob here regarding JWT Authorization on WebAPI. I followed the same tutorials as Brett did and just tried your solution, but using your code I cannot seem to get into any endpoint which has been decorated with [Authorize]. I am still using the code in http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/ to generate my JWT and when using that example it's working fine. Obviously though I cannot have just one allowed audience and would love to get a dynamic solution to work. Could you perhaps share more of your code?

Comment: @MrThursday If you sign the tokens with a single issuer, this will work if you change `ValidIssuers` to `ValidIssuer` and assign to your single issuer. The `Func` is the magic here. I started from the bitoftech article as well.

Comment: @technicallyjosh any chance you could elaborate on what you mean by changing ValidIssuers to ValidIssuer?  My tokens are from a single issuer but I have multiple clients/client secrets.  If you could share some code that would be tremendous.

Comment: As far as I can tell, while this solution may technically work, it requires a round-trip to the database for every request.  It would be preferable if there were a method to update the AllowedAudiences and IssueSecurityTokenProviders each time a new client registered so that the db wouldn't need to be hit with each incoming request.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help out however :D bare in mind I'm a beginner so it might not be the best one :D

I also would like to have dynamic audiences without restarting my services as in the end it about flexibility and ease of use.

Therefore I have my validation as follow :

```
        var bearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                AudienceValidator = AudienceValidator,
                IssuerSigningToken = x509SecToken,
                ValidIssuer = issuer,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,                    
            })
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(bearerOptions);
```

As you can see above I do have a delegate that is validating my audiences. What basically that means - every time you fire off request to your server this method is called to verify audience.

At this moment I have only small debug methods and I'm validating *ANY* audience coming in :

```
    private bool AudienceValidator(IEnumerable<string> audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        Trace.Write("would be validating audience now");
        return true;
    }
```

Now next step is what to do here ? Well for sure you do not want to query DB every time the audience would be validated as that would be omitting purpose of using those tokens :D You might come up with some nice idea - please share then!

### First approach :

So what I have done is using https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler and I have scheduled update of AllowedAudiences from DB every 1 hour. And that works well. I'm registering new audiences with set of rights and in best case they are ready to go on fly or I have to wait like ~59 minutes :)

Hope this helps!

### Second approach :

Now on the second hand I have added claim to JWT token which defines authorized resources. And then I'm checking if in security token I have resource that matches my resource server. If so we consider audience to be validated :D

Answer (score 1):

We also need dynamic JWT audience handler, specifically for Azure B2C tenants. The tenant information is stored in a database which was used to configure individual `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()` entries per tenant and B2C policy (an additional parameter required for using B2C tenants).

We found that trying to add additional entries by trying to use `IAppBuilder` `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication()` after startup simply did not work - the providers where not correctly managed and therefore the signing tokens were not retrieved, resulting in a HTTP 401 challenge. (We kept the `IAppBuiler` object around so it could be used later.)

Looking at the `JwtFormat.cs` code which validates the token provided the clue (we are on version 3.1.0 - YMMV) on how to implement a solution:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/v3.1.0/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt/JwtFormat.cs#L193

This is where it pulls the issuers and signing keys from the supplied `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()`. Note that it is a bit inefficient for our purposes - it pulls ALL the issuers and signing keys, even though only one audience will match the JWT issued by the Azure B2C tenant.

Instead what we did was:

1. Use only one `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication()` call with a no `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()` - just passing the TokenValidationParameters;
2. Use a subclassed `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class and override the `ValidateToken` to dynamically manage the audiences;
3. Create an instance of the subclassed `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` and poke it into `JwtFormat.TokenHandler`.

How you manage and initiate adding new audiences is up to you. We use a database and Redis to deliver the reload command.

Here is the the Startup.Auth.cs snippet:

```
/// <summary>
/// The B2C token handler for handling dynamically loaded B2C tenants.
/// </summary>
protected B2CTokenHandler TokenHandler = new B2CTokenHandler();

/// <summary>
/// Setup the OAuth authentication. We use the database to retrieve the available B2C tenants.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app">The application builder object</param>
public AuthOAuth2(IAppBuilder app) {
    // get Active Directory endpoint
    AadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["b2c:AadInstance"];

    // get the B2C policy list used by API1
    PolicyIdList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["b2c:PolicyIdList"].Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();

    TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters {
        NameClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"
    };

    // create a access token format 
    JwtFormat jwtFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps);

    // add our custom token handler which will provide token validation parameters per tenant
    jwtFormat.TokenHandler = TokenHandler;

    // wire OAuth authentication for tenants
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions {
        // the security token provider handles Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
        AccessTokenFormat = jwtFormat,
        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider() {
            OnValidateIdentity = async (context) => await OAuthValidateIdentity(context)
        }
    });

    // load initial OAuth authentication tenants
    LoadAuthentication();
}

/// <summary>
/// Load the OAuth authentication tenants. We maintain a local hash map of those tenants during
/// processing so we can track those tenants no longer in use.
/// </summary>
protected override void LoadAuthentication() {
    AuthProcessing authProcessing = new AuthProcessing();

    List<B2CAuthTenant> authTenantList = new List<B2CAuthTenant>();

    // add all tenants for authentication
    foreach (AuthTenantApp authTenantApp in authProcessing.GetAuthTenantsByAppId("API1")) {
        // create a B2C authentication tenant per policy. Note that the policy may not exist, and
        // this will be handled by the B2C token handler at configuration load time below
        foreach (string policyId in PolicyIdList) {
            authTenantList.Add(new B2CAuthTenant {
                Audience = authTenantApp.ClientId,
                PolicyId = policyId,
                TenantName = authTenantApp.Tenant
            });
        }
    }

    // and load the token handler with the B2C authentication tenants
    TokenHandler.LoadConfiguration(AadInstance, authTenantList);

    // we must update the CORS origins
    string origins = string.Join(",", authProcessing.GetAuthTenantAuthoritiesByAppId("API1").Select(a => a.AuthorityUri));

    // note some browsers do not support wildcard for exposed headers - there specific needed. See
    //
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers#Browser_compatibility
    EnableCorsAttribute enableCors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, "*", "*", "Content-Disposition");
    enableCors.SupportsCredentials = true;
    enableCors.PreflightMaxAge = 30 * 60;

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(enableCors);
}
```

Here is the snippet for the overridden `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dictionary of currently configured OAuth audience+policy to the B2C endpoint signing key cache.
/// </summary>
protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider> AudiencePolicyMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider>();

/// <summary>
/// Load the B2C authentication tenant list, creating a B2C endpoint security token provider
/// which will bethe source of the token signing keys.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aadInstance">The Active Directory instance endpoint URI</param>
/// <param name="b2cAuthTenantList">The B2C authentication tenant list</param>
public void LoadConfiguration(string aadInstance, List<B2CAuthTenant> b2cAuthTenantList) {
    // maintain a list of keys that are loaded
    HashSet<string> b2cAuthTenantSet = new HashSet<string>();

    // attempt to create a security token provider for each authentication tenant
    foreach(B2CAuthTenant b2cAuthTenant in b2cAuthTenantList) {
        // form the dictionary key
        string tenantKey = $"{b2cAuthTenant.Audience}:{b2cAuthTenant.PolicyId}";

        if (!AudiencePolicyMap.ContainsKey(tenantKey)) {
            try {
                // attempt to create a B2C endpoint security token provider. We may fail if there is no policy 
                // defined for that tenant
                OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider tokenProvider = new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(aadInstance, b2cAuthTenant.TenantName, b2cAuthTenant.PolicyId));

                // add to audience:policy map
                AudiencePolicyMap[tenantKey] = tokenProvider;

                // this guy is new
                b2cAuthTenantSet.Add(tenantKey);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // exception has already been reported appropriately
            }
        } else {
            // this guys is already present
            b2cAuthTenantSet.Add(tenantKey);
        }
    }

    // at this point we have a set of B2C authentication tenants that still exist. Remove any that are not
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider> kvpAudiencePolicy in AudiencePolicyMap.Where(t => !b2cAuthTenantSet.Contains(t.Key))) {
        AudiencePolicyMap.TryRemove(kvpAudiencePolicy.Key, out _);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Validate a security token. We are responsible for priming the token validation parameters
/// with the specific parameters for the audience:policy, if found.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="securityToken">A 'JSON Web Token' (JWT) that has been encoded as a JSON object. May be signed using 'JSON Web Signature' (JWS)</param>
/// <param name="tvps">Contains validation parameters for the security token</param>
/// <param name="validatedToken">The security token that was validated</param>
/// <returns>A claims principal from the jwt. Does not include the header claims</returns>
public override ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters tvps, out SecurityToken validatedToken) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(securityToken)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Security token is null");
    }

    // decode the token as we need the 'aud' and 'tfp' claims
    JwtSecurityToken token = ReadToken(securityToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

    if (token == null) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Security token is invalid");
    }

    // get the audience and policy
    Claim audience = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud);
    Claim policy = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypesB2C.Tfp);

    if ((audience == null) || (policy == null)) {
        throw new SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException("Security token has no audience/policy id");
    }

    // generate the key
    string tenantKey = $"{audience.Value}:{policy.Value}";

    // check if this audience:policy is known
    if (!AudiencePolicyMap.ContainsKey(tenantKey)) {
        throw new SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException("Security token has unknown audience/policy id");
    }

    // get the security token provider
    OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider tokenProvider = AudiencePolicyMap[tenantKey];

    // clone the token validation parameters so we can update
    tvps = tvps.Clone();

    // we now need to prime the validation parameters for this audience
    tvps.ValidIssuer = tokenProvider.Issuer;
    tvps.ValidAudience = audience.Value;
    tvps.AuthenticationType = policy.Value;
    tvps.IssuerSigningTokens = tokenProvider.SecurityTokens;

    // and call real validator with updated parameters
    return base.ValidateToken(securityToken, tvps, out validatedToken);
}
```

For our B2C tenants, it is the case that not all available policies are defined for a tenant. We need to handle that in `OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve the metadata from the endpoint.
/// </summary>
private void RetrieveMetadata() {
    metadataLock.EnterWriteLock();

    try {
        // retrieve the metadata
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = Task.Run(configManager.GetConfigurationAsync).Result;

        // and update
        issuer = config.Issuer;
        securityTokens = config.SigningTokens;
    } catch (Exception ex) when (CheckHttp404(ex)) {
        // ignore 404 errors as they indicate that the policy does not exist for a tenant
        logger.Warn($"Policy endpoint not found for {metadataEndpoint} - ignored");
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.Fatal(ex, $"System error in retrieving token metadatafor {metadataEndpoint}");
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        metadataLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Check if the inner most exception is a HTTP response with status code of Not Found.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ex">The exception being examined for a 404 status code</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool CheckHttp404(Exception ex) {
    // get the inner most exception
    while(ex.InnerException != null) {
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }

    // check if a HttpWebResponse with a 404
    return (ex is WebException webex) && (webex.Response is HttpWebResponse response) && (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem and followed the same path. In addition, I also tried making a custom OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider() passing the IAppBuilder and JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions objects, override the OnValidateIdentity() and reload the JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions there but the new audience is still not validated.

I guess, I will stick to application restart for now to overcome this problem.

Hope this will give a hint for others to the right path.